# android загрузка в Recyclerview больших данных

Tags: java, recyclerview, view, viewholder

Есть R.array.test в котором хранится 11000 итемов

`<array name="l">
        <item>а</item>
           ... 10000
       <item>а</item>
    </array>`

данный массив я отображаю в Recyclerview, и при переключении на нужный фрагмент приложение не сколько секунд тормозит потом отображает информацию.
Подскажите, где и как лучше хранить большой объем и как его лучше подгружать, чтобы было как наименьшие время подгрузки?

Comment: Ресурсы и SharedPreferences по умолчанию в основном потоке считывается. Не знаю, можно ли (по идее да), считывать их в фоновом потоке. Возможно, стоит сохранить ваши данные в БД и оттуда их брать в фоновом потоке. Ну или ресурсы считывать также фоново. После этого должно, по идее, всё ОК быть.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если у вас такой большой объем данных я бы вам рекомендовал их хранить где-то в базе данных и получать их оттуда не все, а по мере скролла списка вниз (я с трудом представляю себе ситуацию в которой вам единовременно понадобится все 11 тыс элементов). Для этого вы можете реализовать пагинацию RecycleView. Можете почитать [здесь](https://habr.com/ru/post/268991/). Так же можно поискать либы, вот [тут](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging) есть даже решение от Google.

Вам конечно придется вероятно заморочиться с созданием запроса в саму базу данных, чтоб получать данные постранично. Для этих целей я бы порекомендовал посмотреть в сторону LiveData + Room.

Но на самом то деле тут решений может быть много, но однозначно не стоит в список грузить все 11 тыс. Но даже если по каким-то причинам вы решили загрузить все 11 тыс, вам нужно все это вынести в фоновый поток, чтоб не грузить ваш UI.